# Let $A= \{x: 0<|x|<1$ and $\frac{1}{x}\notin \mathbb{Z}_{>0}\}$.

Tags: general-topology

Consider the set $Y=[-1.1]$ a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$.  Let  $A= \{x: 0<|x|<1 $ and $\frac{1}{x}\notin \mathbb{Z}_{>0}\}$.

I know that $A$ is  open in the straight, can you help me prove that?

But because $A$ would be open in $Y$, I haven't been able to see that yet. I know that those opened in $Y$ would be the intersections of the common open of the straight with the $Y$. So how do I prove $A$ is open at $Y$?

Comment: $A$ doesn't seem to be a set...Please fix the first line.

Comment: I fixed the writing. Is it better now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understood $Y=[-1,1]$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R$ endowed with the usual topology. The set $A$ is open in $\Bbb R$, being a union of an open set $(-1,0)$ and a family $\{(1/(n+1),1/n):n\in\Bbb N\}$ of open sets. Since $A\subset Y$, $A$ is an open subspace of $Y$.

Comment: $(-1,0)\subset A$

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Oops, I missed this, sorry. Fixed. Thanks for your attention.